# Generalized Ramanujan's identity with hyperbolic cotangent

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Three weeks ago I derived an identity, which generalizes Ramanujan's identity with hyperbolic cotangent. Don't you know is it original or not?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\coth(\pi n)}{n^3}=\frac{7\pi^3}{180}
$$
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\coth(\pi n)\coth(\pi\sqrt{i}n)\coth\left(\pi\frac{n}{\sqrt{i}}\right)}{n^5}=\frac{127\pi^5}{37800}
$$

($\sqrt{i}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$)

Ramanujan's identity might be found on page 293 of notebook II, chapter 14, entry 25.1 (http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan%27s%20Notebooks%20II.pdf)

I have an article, but it is on vixra and nobody takes vixra seriously, but if you are interested it is here http://vixra.org/abs/1510.0364

UPD: using the same methods one can derive that $$-\psi(1-x)\psi(1+x)=\gamma^2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(H_k-\gamma)x^2}{k(k^2-x^2)}$$

($\psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$)

Comment: It looks interesting, but we don't vet articles here for correctness (nor do I see any link to an article). Therefore this question will be closed.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I've edited it. Could you open my question, please?

Comment: Please give a reference for the Ramanujan identity first. Generally, advertisements of one's work are frowned upon here, but the question might be viable if the focus is on requesting a reference for where this might appear in the literature. Have you checked standard sources such as Gradshteyn and Ryzhik? Knowing that you have might get others to take your question more seriously.

Comment: If the OP had asked whether anyone knew a reference for such a result, would people have wanted to close the question? It seems (perhaps with some modification) like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Thanks for speaking up. I generally don't like applying moderator powers (to overrule close votes) without some Community support. I've now reopened.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: OK. I am not sure that the OPs latest edits help, but...

Comment: Danil, are you familiar with Straub's http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5119? The machinery is quite general...

Comment: @WadimZudilin, I've never seen that article before. Thank you